# We have blocked all request from this device, phone auth firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have completed my app for release. It was working fine until I uploaded it on google play. My App uses firebase phone auth and whenever a "NEW USER" requests an OTP It goes to the browser for captcha. when it comes back it says

`[firebase_auth/too-many-requests] We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.`

How it is too many requests even on a fresh new device? I don't even know what code to send so I am adding GitHub link - https://github.com/DoomDoc/facelift_app/tree/app7

[Photo of error on a new device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zez0.jpg)